# Change mapping option replaced with cloak option in TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

I want to change the mapping location for trunk in TFS and get latest but instead of 'change mapping' I now have the option to 'cloak'. What do I need to do in order to get the 'change mapping' option back again? I can't see a way to change the mapped folder because there is only cloak option available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend installing "TFS Source Control Explorer Extension" -

From below link:
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/af70cbb7-1e0d-4d16-bc57-cccc15370c51

Answer (score 1):

I also got a machine with VS2015 that the Mapping/remove mapping option was replaced with cloak/uncloak option

I found the  issue was to do if the parent folder was mapped. As a result you can't map a child folder it doesn't give you the map option anymore but the cloak option.

Solution is to remove the parent mapping then the child option won't have cloak anymore.